# Multiple reverse lookup on an association table

Tags: activerecord, sqlite

I've got a table that look roughly like this. Each link can have an arbitrary number of locations.

```
| link | location
| aa   |  1
| aa   |  2
| aa   |  3
| bb   |  1      <== location can belong to multiple links
| bb   |  3
| cc   |  4
```

I would like a query that takes a set of locations and returns the link they correspond to. Example expected results:

```
given {1}          => no result, null etc.
given {1,2}        => no result, null etc.
given {1, 2, 3}    => result 'aa'
given {3, 2, 1}    => result 'aa'
given {1, 2, 3, 4} => no result, null etc.
given {4}          => result 'cc'
```

Ideally I would run this database-side as an SQL query, specifically in Rails Active Record on sqlite3, however this is not unimportant as I'm after a general approach rather than a specific solution.

I've considered group-by but the table could be huge and I would like the lookup to be quick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A query with `GROUP BY` certainly is simple:

```sql
SELECT link
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY link
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
   AND COUNT(location IN (1, 2, 3)) = 3
```

To avoid having to compute the counts for all links, you could try to filter out links without any of the required locations in a first step:

```sql
SELECT link
FROM MyTable
WHERE link IN (SELECT link
               FROM MyTable
               WHERE location IN (1, 2, 3))
GROUP BY link
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
   AND COUNT(location IN (1, 2, 3)) = 3
```

Whether this helps in practice depends on the distribution of values in your actual data.